# Adding blank option to rails select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im using jquery chained, and Im trying to get the second drop down list to gray out if the first has a blank option selected. Im assuming I need a blank option in the second list for it to lock out, but I'm not sure how to add a blank option. Here is the select option

```
<%= select_tag :equipment, options_for_select(Equipment.all.collect
                                            { |e| ["#{e.model} - #{e.serialNum}",e.id, 
                                            :class =>"#{e.handReceipt}"]},
                                            html_options = {:id=>'equipment'}) %>
```

The first drop down list lets you select the hand receipt type, and with jquery chained, the second list only shows records with the appropriate hand receipt attribute.

How would I add a blank option to the above select?

Edit- Here is what I've tried so far -

```
<%= select_tag :equipment, 
     options_for_select(  [["--",""],
                          Equipment.all.collect{ |e|
                          ["#{e.model} - #{e.serialNum}",
                          e.id, :class =>"#{e.handReceipt}"]}],
                          html_options = {:id=>'equipment'}) %>
```

This results in an improper display of the list-

```
<select id="equipment" name="equipment">
   <option value="">--</option>
   <option value="[&quot;M4 - W432156&quot;, 10, {:class=&gt;&quot;Arms Room&quot;}]">[&quot;PSN-13 - 176985&quot;, 1, {:class=&gt;&quot;Commo&quot;}]</option>
</select>
```

Instead of showing all the records in the table, it just shows a blank option and the second option.

```
<%= select_tag :equipment, 
     options_for_select(  :include_blank => true,
                          Equipment.all.collect{ |e|
                          ["#{e.model} - #{e.serialNum}",
                          e.id, :class =>"#{e.handReceipt}"]},
                          html_options = {:id=>'equipment'}) %>
```

Results in the following error -

```
C:/Users/Sam/Documents/ruby/btrp/app/views/vehicles/edit.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
                          e.id, :class =>"#{e.handReceipt}"]},
```

Comment: Note that your `html_options` is wrong. You need to use a hash format, so `:html_options => { :id => 'equipment' }` is the correct

Comment: Noted and fixed. It was setting it up properly before and didn't throw an error. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your parameters at `options_for_select` is wrong, I think that's the right way:

```
<%= select_tag :equipment,
      options_for_select(Equipment.all.collect { |e|
                           ["#{e.model} - #{e.serialNum}", e.id,
                            { :class =>"#{e.handReceipt}" }]}), 
      :include_blank => true,
      :id => 'equipment' %>
```

Read more at:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any thoughts on how to get a blank option into the select?

Comment: Well damn. Haha I've been sitting trying to get this to work all morning. I thought the include_blank would be under the options_for_select. Guess I've got to sink more time into deciphering the help syntax. I've read and re-read that page a thousand times already. Thanks for the help!

Comment: On that note, according to the page, if you replace true with 'string', it'll display the string in the box. For whatever reason, the page won't display the string I'm passing to the :include_blank. Any thoughts? Here is what I put in...

:include_blank => '--'

Comment: To this you need to use `:prompt => '--'`, forget `:include_blank` [look at docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag).

Answer (score 0):

You can append the blank value like this.

```
<%= select_tag "category","<option value=''>Category</option>" +  options_from_collection_for_select(@store_categories, "id", "name",params[:category].to_i)%>
```